# UI gets stuck even if I use GCD

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

When I go back from my secondView to my mainView I'm processing something in the viewDidDisappear method of my secondView. The problem is, my mainView gets stuck due to the work the app has to do.

Here is what I do:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    dbq = [[dbqueries alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"abc" object:nil];
    //the notification should start a progressView, but because the whole view gets stuck, I can't see it working, because it stops as soon as the work is done

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //work    

    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform your work in the `dispatch_async` to your `queue`. You are currently doing the work (assuming the `// Work` comment is where it goes) in the main thread, and in addition you are blocking your worker thread waiting for this work.

Try to rearrange your GCD calls a bit:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dbq = [[dbqueries alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"abc" object:nil];

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        // Perform work here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           // Update UI here

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is that he's doing the work on the main thread.

Comment: The view still gets stuck and no loadingindicator

Comment: So I have to create another thread? But do I have to use this GCD thingy then? Because, if its on another thread, why would I need this?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Good spot, missed the // work comment there :). I updated the answer.

Comment: @Krumelur I have another problem now =/
when the work is done, a method in the mainView gets called, but it won't do these two lines now     [self.progressView setHidden:YES];
    [[self.progressView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] stopAnimating];

Comment: Isn't it possible to access the UI from an async thread? But that wouldn't make sense because this line works: self.startARButton.enabled = YES;
it is just before the two other lines

Comment: You should always update UI from the main thread. Use `dispatch_async` again when the UI needs updating. See my updated answer.